# Writing array to filtered and grouped table fails

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am having trouble writing an array defined in VBA to a range in a table that has been grouped and filtered.

Writing an array to a table range is done using:

```
Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).ListRows(1).Range = MyArray
```

This works fine on a filtered table (i.e. filtering the rows using the filter buttons in the row headers). It also works fine in a grouped table (i.e. with some columns grouped using Data --> Outline --> Group.

However, when combining this, the array is not written to the cells in a correct manner. An array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] is written as [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5], if I group columns 2 and 3 in the table. This is NOT the case, if I haven't also filtered the table.

Do anyone have an idea what's going on here? An example workbook can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnV6w5QgXk-jjdtx-iP_Jwa5iaN80Q). It contains a simple table and one sub that tries to write an array to the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

BR
Torben

Comment: Fascinating. I played around and didn't find a method that worked consistently except for changing the outline level to expose the groups before assigning then closing again.

Comment: OK, so I have figured out a workaround/verification that this is a bug in Excel. If you select a cell outside the table range before inserting the array, it works fine - even when both filtering and grouping is active. Why this is the case, I have no idea. It's a clumsy solution (I'm not fond of selecting cells through VBA), but it works.

Comment: Remember to post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have figured out a workaround/verification that this is a bug in Excel. If you select a cell outside the table range before inserting the array, it works fine - even when both filtering and grouping is active. Why this is the case, I have no idea. It's a clumsy solution (I'm not fond of selecting cells through VBA), but it works.

(Sorry, I originaly posted it as a comment, and not an answer).

If anyone has a more elegant solution, I would still be very interested in seeing it.