# Write Array to Range that is filtered

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, range

I have an array that I want to write to a column of a sheet.
Usually I just do
`rngRangeObject = varArray`

However, if there is a filter active on the column, the results are ... unexpected.

If you run the sample code below on a sheet without filters, it works fine.
If you add a filter for column 1 so that the values in cells A4, A7, A10, A13, A16 are hidden you get the following result in the (visible) cells. The filtered cells remain untouched :

[Screenshot results on filtered column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr8Kf.png)

[image]

My first thought that it was linked the different areas and that Excel would for some reason always start over again with every area, but that's not the case. A5:A6 is one area and both cells are filled with "1".
A14:A15 is one area, and it is filled with 1 and 2.

Anyone with an explanation and a fast way to write an array to a filtered column (including the filtered cells) without removing the filters?

Fun fact : There is no issue if you hide these rows without using a filter.

Here's the sample code :

```
Sub WriteArrayToRange()
    Dim varArr(1 To 18, 1 To 1) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objRng As Range
    
    For i = 1 To 18
        varArr(i, 1) = i
    Next
    
    Set objRng = Range("A1:A18")
    
    objRng = varArr
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365995/writing-array-to-filtered-and-grouped-table-fails  (though that's referring to a Table/Listobject, and the suggested workaround does not work here, the observed behaviour is the same...)

Comment: For a regular filtered range: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159073/copying-an-array-to-a-filtered-range-gives-irrational-results

Comment: Since your context is _not_ a `ListObject` there is no restriction on using a [CustomView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.customview) - you could create one when your filter is active, de-activate the filter to copy your data, and then, with a simple method call re-activate your Filter (via the previously-created 'CustomView')

Comment: Thank you @[Tim Williams] and @Spectral Instance, I will give the CustomView a try.